# Web-scraping in php and ajax loading in html only specific class

Tags: php, ajax, class, web-scraping, load

I'm trying to load an external url, scraping with php, grabber.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.websiteurl.com');
 function get_content($URL){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}

echo get_content('https://www.websiteurl.com');
?>
```

and call it with .js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.mywebsite.com/grabber.php?url=https://www.websiteurl.com",
  type: "GET",
  success: function (data) {
    // All posts w/same class
    const Posts = $(data).find(".some__class").get();
...
```

which is loaded in index.html.

When I load the index.html page, it loads all the scraped website, and then display the `.some__class`; the page is very heavy because there are thousand posts.
How can I load only the `.some__class` posts I need?

Comment: Which posts do you "need"? In what way do they differ from the other posts with the class `.some__class`?

Comment: In the scraped website there are lots of classes; I want to load only divs with `.some__class` as class, but do not load other divs. Now in my index.html, it loads everything from the scraped website, then it displays the `.some__class` divs.

Comment: You need to do the proper [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempt yourself first. There are many questions out there about scraping web sites using PHP. We're glad to help you sort specific issues out you might run into, but a proper answer here would require us to write it all for you (which we're not here to do). The posted code doesn't contain any attempt of scraping at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if I seemed superficial, but it's not. I researched and tried for months with no relevant results and then, a the end, I wrote here my question to confront it to your ideas.

Comment: You have to read the complete HTML code, the URL is pointing to, into PHP, there's no avoiding that, but then in PHP you can do what you now do in Javascript: Select out the posts from the HTML. In Javascript you use JQuery, in PHP you would use a DOM parser. You would then only have to return the posts from the AJAX call.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for your help! I'm trying to scrape a newspaper website.
I used your ideas, and I get the divs with the same class
`$doc = new DOMDocument();  @$doc->loadHTML($content);  
classname="block__item";  
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);  
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");  
foreach ($spaner as $value) {. 
echo $doc->saveXML($value);}`  
The problem, now, is that it cannot display images there are annidate in the divs. I tried different ways but I had no significant result!

Comment: The image tags have a `src` attribute that refers to the source of the images. You need to scrape those from the website as well and save them. See: [<img>: The Image Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for you reply. Btw, I tried but nothing, still cannot display the images.